# Pyplot: How do I add a second x-axis that corresponds to y-values from the first x-axis?

Tags: matplotlib

I have a 3 equal length data arrays representing physical quantities: fractional radius (r/R), fractional mass (m/M) and some physical parameter (p).

```
r/R   m/M   P

r1    m1    p1
r2    m2    p2
.     .     .
.     .     .
```

r/R and m/M do not have a functional relationship.

I want to plot P vs r/R, but on the second x-axis have the ticks with values of m/M that correspond to the same values of P.

I tried using twiny():

```
ax.plot(r/r0, P, c='blue')
ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.plot(m/m0, P,c='red')
```

but the result is that the the ticks with values of m/M correspond to different values of P (blurry image attached)

How do I get the ticks on both x-axes to line up, but have the m/M values correspond to the same P values plotted for r/R?

[image]

Comment: There must be a relationship between `r/R` and `m/M`, otherwise, how do you expect the ticks to match up? Can you plot `m/M` vs. `r/R` to explore the relationship between the two? Once you know the relation, the rest is pretty easy

Comment: If you don't have any explicit relationship between r and m, you will need to make the implicit relationship given by your data table explicit. E.g. via `numpy.interp`. Then you need to decide how you want to show your values on the axes, i.e. do you want automatically chosen ticks on both axes or do you want to tick the same positions in axes coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relationship between `r/R` and `m/M`, you could define a new set of ticks and then give the ticks labels manually.

```
new_tick_locations = np.array([0, .2, 1])
ax2.set_xticks(new_tick_locations)
ax2.set_xticklabels(('m1', 'm2', ...))
```